# When is WorldLoadEvent triggered?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

I thought **init** stands for when a world is first created and **load** for when that world is loaded after a server restart. But in both case WorldInitEvent is triggered.

So when is WorldLoadEvent triggered? The docs didn't help explain.

http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/doxygen/d7/dba/classorg_1_1bukkit_1_1event_1_1world_1_1WorldLoadEvent.html
http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/doxygen/dd/dc8/classorg_1_1bukkit_1_1event_1_1world_1_1WorldInitEvent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorldInitEvent --> startup of the server (see [here](https://github.com/Bukkit/CraftBukkit/blob/master/src/main/java/org/bukkit/craftbukkit/CraftServer.java#L982))

WorldLoadEvent --> whenever a world is loaded (due to plugins or NMS/OBC code)

**Edit 07/31/14 changed line number to match 1.7.10**

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure of these things:

Init is when its PREPARING to load up the world. The load would be when its reading the chunks and entities and tile entities, ect.

Id advise looking at the bukkit source for more info:
Bukkit API: https://github.com/Bukkit/Bukkit
CraftBukkit (actual server): https://github.com/EvilSeph/CraftBukkit